# Нужно отправлять письма с VPS сервера

Tags: php, ubuntu, email, vps, smtp

Ситуация следующая:

Есть VPS сервер Ubuntu14.04.

На нем лежит много сайтов, написанных на php. Вот появился еще один, которому нужно при определенных действиях отправлять письма (например, при оформлении заказа отсылать письмо пользователю с no-reply@exampl.com).

Почтовые ящики созданы на pdd.yandex.ru

Как можно отправлять письма от этих ящиков?

Пытался что то настраивать postfix и exim4, но ничего не получилось. Максимум, что я смог - это отправить письмо из терминала себе через exim4, но пришло оно от root@example.com

Не понимаю последовательность действий от "отправка письма в php" до "получение письма пользователем", что нужно настраивать? Вообще, нужны ли эти postfix или exim4?

Comment: *Не понимаю последовательность действий от "отправка письма в php"* — а само это действие («отправка») вы понимаете? если нет, то рекомендую подтянуть свои знания по поводу протокола smtp. в будущем — не помешает. предуведомление: ликбез по какому-либо вопросу — это уже вне тематики данного сайта.

Comment: Таки да, тут нужен ликбез по самим принципам работы почты, а за этим не сюда

Comment: @Demyan112rv Используйте smtp от yandex . Отправляете почту через него.

Comment: Идея сайта отвечать на конкретные краткие практические вопросы. Человек задал конкретный краткий практический вопрос. Ответить на него можно конкретно и кратко. Так что все правильно человек вопрос задал. Странно, что вопросы типа "Как отсортировать массив?" сомнений не вызывают.

Answer (score 2):

В приложении вашего сайта можно использовать PHP библиотеку для отправки email сообщений, например [PhpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Самое главное, эта библиотека умеет **отправлять письма через SMTP**. В Вашем случае через почтовый ящик, который был создан через pdd.yandex.ru, с нужным адресом отправителя. Библиотека очень простая и удобная. Помимо этого, подобные библиотеки очень удобны для отправки email сообщений в HTML, с вложениями и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой в одном проекте - письма, отосланные напрямую с сервера воспринимались как спамовые (яндекс прописывает DKIM запись).
В проекте использовался класс для отсылки:
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/mail.php

В итоге нашел решение. Самое главное отличие было в **хосте** для подключения:
**ssl://smtp.yandex.ru**
порт 465.

В этом случае php прозрачно устанавливает ssl соединение, а дальше работает smtp почтовик.
Ключевая разница - письма отсылает сам яндекс со всеми корректными подписями, а мылер на самом сервере толком и не нужен в таком случае.